# Android Google Maps v2 big memory consumption

Tags: android, google-maps, memory, out-of-memory, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an application which crashes after using it for some time on a tablet with `OutOfMemoryError`. My application uses master-details layout with `Fragments`. After doing a lot of debugging I came to the conclusion that big memory consumption is caused by maps which are used in the details view.

I created an example as simple as I could which may lack many important features but demonstrates the problem.

TestMapActivity:

```
public class TestMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_map_activity);
}

public void newMap(View view) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapFrame, new TestMapFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
}
```

Activity's layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="newMap"
    android:text="new map" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TestMapFragment:

```
public class TestMapFragment extends Fragment {

protected MapView mMapView;
protected GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView = new MapView(REdroid.sContext);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_map_fragment, container, false);
    ((FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.mapFrame)).addView(mMapView);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mMapView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mMapView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
};

private final void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = mMapView.getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

protected void setUpMap() {
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    }
}

}
```

Fragment's layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

I'm launching the activity and pressing the button to show the map. When I'm checking memory consumption with DDMS I can see that each time I press "new map" the "Allocated" memory grows by around 0.5MB. As you can imagine It's really a problem when user watches many items (which is quite normal behaviour in my app) and the app takes 5MB each 10 items (actually in the real app it takes 1MB for each view).

Is this normal? What can I do to stop the app from using this much memory? I read here about Google Maps having some memory leaks but can they be this big?

**EDIT**

I corrected the TestMapActivity.newMap() function. I added adding transaction to the stack because the memory "leak" doesn't occur if I the operation isn't put to backstack.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when i switch between two fragments, each one has it MapView.

Adding this to my code solved the huge memory consumption problem:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    mMapView.clear()
    mMapView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if the GC in LogCat are annoying to you (I think they are), then you can remove them by a filter by message: ^(?!.*(GC_)|(Cache)).*$.

Secondly, you should reuse you MapFragment, or at least remove it and recreate it.

Something like:

```
    public class TestMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        GoogleMapFragment map;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.test_map_activity);

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // to handle orientation change
                map = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("map");
            }
        }

        public void newMap(View view) {
            if (map == null)
                 map = new TestMapFragment();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.mapFrame, map, "map").commit();
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

After your comment about that you use MapView, I searched the API on MapView and from: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html

```
onDestroy()
    You must call this method from the parent Activity/Fragment's corresponding method.
```

Are you doing this?

**Edit2**

Just noticed that you in onCreate of your fragment do:

```
mMapView = new MapView(REdroid.sContext);
```

how about deleting that line and instead in setupMapIfNeeded:

```
private final void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
if (mMapView == null) {
    mMapView = new MapView(context);
}
if (mMap == null) {
    mMap = mMapView.getMap();
    if (mMap != null) {
        setUpMap();
    }
}

}
```

Also I think i would furthermore do a setRetainInstance(true) in onCreate of the fragment.

Comment: As you can see I'm not using Google's `MapFragment` but `MapView` embedded in ordinary `Fragment`. Actually the map is just one little piece in a big view in the real app. The above example is constructed this way just to be simple.
Reusing the `Fragment` isn't that easy because the real scenario can be more complicated then just displaying many details `Fragments` one after the other.

Comment: If you take a look at the `TestMapFragment` code you'll see that I do call all `MapView` lifecycle functions.

Comment: and you are positive that your fragment indeed gets its onDestroy function called?

Comment: Actually it's not being called but do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? We came here to another thing bothering me - I didn't found anything in Google's docs about how exactly should I handle `MapView` in a `Fragment`.

Comment: Think I would explicitly call onDestroy on the mapview when you call new view to make sure that you do not have another running in the background. Still keeping you current code though, so that when fragment eventually get destroyed the mapview does too. I am not familiar with using the mapview so cannot give any direction other than my idea about how it works.

Comment: Moving MapView.onDestroy() to onDestroyView() which IS called didn't help.

Comment: I noticed that it happens only if I add transaction to backstack.